# Butcher's Tableau and Runge-Kutta 4

Tags: numerical-methods

I have been reading about RK4 and one thing that I am not able to understand is **how to determine the coefficients to use**?

I found extensive information about Butcher's table (see [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveExplicitRungeKutta.html#689939648) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butcher_tableau#Explicit_Runge.E2.80.93Kutta_methods) for instance). Though some properties must be satisfied (such as $\sum_{i=1}^{s} b_{i}=1$). Yet, how to exactly get the values of each coefficient is something that I don't understand and can't find information. Many sources say that the coefficients are some free parameters that must satisfy some Taylor expansion: but how, specifically?

Comment: [*Here*](http://nptel.iitm.ac.in/courses/111104030/pdf_lectures/lecture9.pdf) you can see the derivation of those values. Normally, you just look up all of these coefficients and algorithm as it become very tedious algebra and are not deriving those. The Butcher table is just a shorthand for those. Regards

Comment: I am guessing that I should look into the work of Butcher if I want to understand them huh?

Comment: It is really just a short-form notation. He wrote a book and here are his notes from it (you can see his book title here): http://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~butcher/ODE-book-2008/Tutorials/RK-methods.pdf. Regards

Comment: Ok, those notes are really cool. Thanks!

Comment: You are very welcome! Please note that there are even newer variants of RK, like Runge-Kutta-Merson (RKM), an improvement over RK4, and Runge-Kutta-Fehlberg (RKF) and an improved RKF variant called the Cash-Karp-Runge-Kutta (CKRK) method. Regards

Comment: Could you gather these comments into one answer please? I think they already provide a lot of information necessary to answer the post ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is interesting to note that the Runge - Kutta method is the Midpoint (order two), Modified Euler or Huen, order three and then we step up to RK4.

It is also worth noting that the computing accuracy does not improve significantly for fifth or higher order RK methods, but the computational complexity increases rapidly.

Here are some relevant notes per your question and request.

- You can see the derivation [*here*](http://nptel.ac.in/courses/111104030/pdf_lectures/lecture9.pdf) for some of those values (from Lecture 9 of NPTEL's Numerical solution of ODEs - Sept 2011).
- Normally, you just look up all of these coefficients and algorithm as it become very tedious algebra and are not deriving those.
- The Butcher table is just a shorthand for those. He wrote a book and here are his [*notes*](http://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~butcher/ODE-book-2008/Tutorials/RK-methods.pdf) from it in which he discusses this shorthand.
- Please note that there are even newer variants of RK, like Runge-Kutta-Merson (RKM), an improvement over RK4, and Runge-Kutta-Fehlberg (RKF) and an improved RKF variant called the Cash-Karp-Runge-Kutta (CKRK) method.
- You might also be interested in this other set of very nice [*notes*](http://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~butcher/CONFERENCES/JAPAN/KYUSHU/kyushu-slides.pdf).

Comment: Nice post! and a nice green $\checkmark$, too ;-)

Comment: I just wish I had more of your posts to read! I'll have to revisit a handful of your answers to help refresh some things, and to get some references!

Comment: Looks inviting. Yes, it would be helpful to know what is meant there by homogenous. Hopefully, you'll get a response!

Comment: The derivation link is dead now :(

Comment: One can read the founding articles of Karl Heun and Wilhelm Kutta in the original <s>Klingon</s>German at [Zeits. f. Math. Phys. vol 45, p. 23](https://archive.org/details/zeitschriftfrma01runggoog/page/n32) and [Zeits. f. Math. Phys. vol 46, p. 435](https://archive.org/details/zeitschriftfrma12runggoog/page/n449). I summarized their content [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2527316/115115)

Comment: down voting because the 2nd paragraph is very wrong. Tsit5, Vern7, and Vern9 are all better than rk4 for sufficiently strict tolerance