# What's the motivation for Runge-Kutta methods?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

Recently, I have been taking a course on ODEs and learning Runge-Kutta methods. To be specific, the 4th order Runge-Kutta method on solving initial value problems.

My instructor and the textbook told me the formula but didn't say anything about the thoughts behind the method. I wrote some code and found that the Runge-Kutta method does perform better than the Euler method, but I can't understand why.

Is anyone willing to give me a hand on how to get the formula of Runge-Kutta? Thanks!

Comment: It 'does perform better than Euler method' because the RK4 method uses 4 stages to get an approximation as opposed to the Euler method which uses 1 stage. See [here](http://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/NumInt/NumIntFourth.html) for a good description of the method. You can find the derivation in most numerical analysis books.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/528856/explanation-and-proof-of-the-fourth-order-runge-kutta-method This question is duplicated! See this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### On the history

See Butcher: [A History of the Runge-Kutta method](http://people.cs.vt.edu/~asandu/Public/Qual2011/DiffEqn/Butcher_1996_RK-history.pdf)

In summary, people (Nystroem, Runge, Heun, Kutta,...) at the end of the 19th century experimented with success in generalizing the methods of numerical integration of functions in one variable $$\int_a^bf(x)dx,$$ like the Gauss, trapezoidal, midpoint and Simpson methods, to the solution of differential equations, which have an integral form $$y(x)=y_0+\int_{x_0}^x f(s,y(s))\,ds.$$

---

Carl Runge in 1895<sup>[1]</sup>  came up with ("by some curious inductive process" - "auf einem eigentümlich induktiven Wege" wrote Heun 5 years later) the 4-stage 3rd order method
\begin{align}
k_1&=f(x,y)Δx,\\
k_2&=f(x+\tfrac12Δx,y+\tfrac12k_1)Δx\\
k_3&=f(x+Δx,y+k_1)Δx\\
k_4&=f(x+Δx,y+k_3)Δx\\
y_{+1}&=y+\tfrac16(k_1+4k_2+k_4)
\end{align}

<sub>[1] *"Über die numerische Auflösung von Differentialgleichungen"*, Math. Ann. 46, p. 167-178</sub>

---

Inspired by this Karl Heun in 1900<sup>[2]</sup> explored methods of the type
$$
\left.\begin{aligned}k^i_m &= f(x+ε^i_mΔx,y+ε^i_mk^{i+1}_m)Δx,~~ i=1,..,s,\\ k^{s+1}_m&=f(x,y)Δx\end{aligned}\right\},~~ m=1,..,n\\
y_{+1}=y+\sum_{m=1}^n\alpha_mf(x+ε^0_mΔx,y+ε^0_mk^1_m)Δx
$$
He computed the order conditions by Taylor expansion and constructed methods of this type up to order 4, however the only today recognizable Runge-Kutta methods among them are the order-2 Heun-trapezoidal method and the order 3 Heun method.

<sub>[2] *"Neue Methode zur approximativen Integration der Differentialgleichungen einer unabhängigen Veränderlichen"*, Z. f. Math. u. Phys. 45, p. 23-38</sub>

---

Wilhelm Kutta in his publication one year later in 1901<sup>[3]</sup> considered the scheme of Heun wasteful in the number of function evaluations and introduced what is today known as explicit Runge-Kutta methods, where each new function evaluation potentially contains all previous values in the $y$ update. 
\begin{align}
k_1&=f(x,y)Δx,\\
k_m&=f(x+c_mΔx, y+a_{m,1}k_1+...+a_{m,m-1}k_{m-1})Δx,&& m=2,...,s\\[0.5em]
y_{+1}&=y+b_1k_1+...+b_sk_s
\end{align}
He computed order conditions and presented methods up to order $5$ in parametrization and examples. He especially noted the 3/8 method for its symmetry and small error term and the "classical" RK4 method for its simplicity in using always only the last function value in the $y$ updates.

<sub>[3] *"Beitrag zur näherungsweisen Lösung totaler Differentialgleichungen"*, Z. f. Math. u. Phys. 46, p. 435-453</sub>

---

### On the order dependence of the performance

The *Euler method* has global error order 1. Which means that to get an error level of $10^{-8}$ (on well-behaved example problems) you will need a step size of $h=10^{-8}$. Over the interval $[0,1]$ this requires $10^8$ steps with $10^8$ function evaluations.

The classical *RK4 method* has error order 4. To get an error level of $10^{-8}$ you will thus need a step size of $h=0.01$. Over the interval $[0,1]$ this requires $100$ steps with $400$ function evaluations.

If you decrease the step by a factor of $10$ to $h=0.001$, the *RK4 method* will need $1000$ steps with $4000$ function evaluations to get an error level of $10^{-12}$. This is still much less effort than used in the *Euler example* above with a much better result.

Using `double` precision floating point numbers you will not get a much better result with any method using a fixed step size, as smaller step sizes result in an accumulating floating point noise that dominates the error of the method.