# Why the weights are 1-2-2-1 in Runge-Kutta method?

Tags: numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

The well-known 4th order Runge-Kutta formula for the ODE $y'=f(x,y(x)$ is given by
$$y_{n+1} = y_{n} + \dfrac{1}{6}h(K_1 + 2 K_2 + 2K_3 +K_4),$$
where $K_1,K_2,K_3,K_4$ are essentially approximations for the slopes of $y=y(x)$ at four points.

Why are the weights 1-2-2-1? What would happen if we change the formula to $$y_{n+1} = y_{n} + \dfrac{1}{4}h(K_1 +  K_2 + K_3 +K_4)?$$

Comment: Strictly speaking, the weights are $1/6, 1/3, 1/3, 1/6$. But yes, there is a [derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods#Derivation_of_the_Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_fourth-order_method) of it, this one from over there on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

Kutta found this example when looking for 4th order methods that have symmetric final weights, $b_1=b_4$, $b_2=b_3$, together with the condition that as quadrature method, that is for trivial ODE $y'(x)=f(x)$, the method should devolve to the Simpson rule. This already fixes the $b_i$ and $c_i$.

If I remember correctly, this also fixes the matrix coefficients $a_{ij}$.

On the other hand, there are not degrees of freedom left when the strictly lower triangular matrix $a_{ij}$ has only non-zero entries on the sub-diagonal.

See [How to derive 4th Runge-Kutta?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3436705/how-to-derive-4th-runge-kutta/3437815#3437815) for a bit more on the sub-diagonal pattern, [Explanation and proof of the 4th order Runge-Kutta method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/528856/explanation-and-proof-of-the-4th-order-runge-kutta-method/4666744#4666744) for a heuristic approach to the structure of RK4.